# Do we have an algorithm to solve this type of matrix equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

$\begin{pmatrix}
f(t)\\ 
g(t)\\ 
h(t)
\end{pmatrix}= A\begin{pmatrix}
w(t)\\ 
k(t)\\ 
s(t) 
\end{pmatrix}$
Where $A$ is a $3\times3$ matrix

How to solve this ? Suppose we know everything except from $A$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A$ has 9 total unknowns, and each point $t$ gives you 3 equations, it would potentially suffice to evaluate the expression at three different times $t$, and then solve the resulting system.

Comment: More broadly: you can evaluate at many different values of $t$, getting an over-constrained system, and use a [_Least Squares_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) fit to determine the values of $A$..